# Routing in rails 5.2

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a RoR app with an admin_controller, the admin is able to CRUD Item, now I am a bit confused when it comes to routing. How can I create the app in a way that I can have a link to new_item be like: admin/item/new instead of creating an item controller with a authenticate_admin? method (since I use Device)

All in all how is this kind of routing achieved in rails

e.g. admin/orders/:id
or
store/sales/lates

Comment: Why don't you go through [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html), try defining the routes for your application, and update the question if you still face any issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally , your `admin_controller` shouldn't do any CURD actions on an `Item` object. You should use an `items_controller` for that.

to achieve what you are trying to do, you can use an admin name space and maybe get the `item_controller` to be inherited from the admin controller.

So, you can have something like,

```
#app/controllers
AdminController < ApplicationController

end

#app/controllers/admin/
module Admin
  ItemsController < AdminController

  end
end

#config/routes
namespace :admin do
  resources :items
end
```

[rails namespaces](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)

Comment: Awesome. what you saying makes sense thank you i'll definitely try this out

Comment: I was able to achieve the routing part now I am stuck in showing the items after successfully saving to database , I get an error saying "undefined method tittle" when tryng to run @items.tittle

Comment: @JusticeM, It's hard to tell without looking at the actual error with the code. However, assuming you are using the standard rails way, It should be `@item` , not @items. `@items` is a list of items and `@item` represent only one item object. So, if you want to get the title, you will have to do `@item.title`

Comment: @item.title gives me a "NoMethodError in Admin::Items#show".....saying "undefined method `tittle' for nil:NilClass"

Comment: @JusticeM, it looks like your `@item` variable is nil (null). Since it's a different issue than the question you asked above, Post it as a seperate question with your code and the error (stack trace), then me or someone else can help you out. Because it's hard to say the reason without seeing the code.